# How do I stop a function running on a page change in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a new function on an API response. Now the problem is when routing to a new page the functions created on the last page are still running. Is it possible to have the created functions only run on that page?

I am quite new to React and also I don't really know how to ask this question better.

```
.then((data) => {
  var functionData= data;
  var Function=new Function (functionData);

  return(Function());
})
```

Comment: Why do you create a function like this in the first place?

Comment: That's the way I found I could do what I need to do. The data coming in is a function that I need to run for the front-end user. If there is a better way to do something like that I would love to hear your suggestions @Konrad